# DRF - Check user permissions

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to check the permissions of the user in each method so, before the call reach the method handler the permissions must have been checked (DRY). According to the documentation `initial` enables me to do this but, is this a good practice?

```
class StorageDetail(APIView):

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not has_permission(request):
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        super(StorageDetail, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, storage_id):
        # ....

    def put(self, request, storage_id):
        # ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not a good practice. According to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) it is better to use Permission class.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Adding customers not allowed.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True


class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, CustomerAccessPermission,)
```